# cakePHP, processing a huge table in a loop

Tags: for-loop, cakephp-1.3, cursor-position

I have a table (3,000,000 records) which I need to process.
I've created a for loop, using SQL COUNT result for the upper boundary.
Now I need to iterate through each row, manipulate some data and save it back to the DB.
The manipulation and updates are simple, what I ask is: how do I query every pass, the next row from the table?

- I know that I can use a resource and iterate it.
- using basic php it's possible to use the db cursor, how can i do it using cakePHP?

Anyone?

Comment: do you need to process this data just once or regulary? What is the database??

Comment: Once in a while, monthly.
MySQL

Comment: Your best bet is to use a stored procedure. You can easily call it via Cake.